# Use of texture in extrude geometry (GWT)

Tags: java, gwt

I'm creating shapes with extrude geometry on GWT, now I want to apply textures on it but I am not able to apply it directly. How can I do that?

My code looks like :

```
ExtrudeGeometry extrudeMaterialBoard = null;
shapeExtrude.getExtrudeSettings().amount = (int) getMaterialThickness();
shapeExtrude.getExtrudeSettings().curveSegments = 1;
shapeExtrude.getExtrudeSettings().bevelThickness= 5;
shapeExtrude.getExtrudeSettings().bevelSize= 5;
shapeExtrude.getExtrudeSettings().bevelEnabled= true;
shapeExtrude.getExtrudeSettings().material = 0;
shapeExtrude.getExtrudeSettings().extrudeMaterial = 1;
extrudeMaterialBoard = new ExtrudeGeometry(DrawShape.getBottomBoard(), shapeExtrude.getExtrudeSettings()); 

  camera = new PerspectiveCamera(
    70, // fov
    getRenderer().getAbsoluteAspectRation(), // aspect 
    1, // near
    1000 // far 
);
camera.getPosition().setZ(400);
String texture1 = "uvgrid0.jpg";
MeshBasicMaterial material = new MeshBasicMaterial();
material.setColor(getColor(COLOR_TRANSPARENT));
Texture texture = new Texture(texture1); 
material.setMap(texture);
mesh = new Mesh(extrudeMaterialBoard, material);
getScene().add(mesh);
getRenderer().render(getScene(), camera);
```

If I use cube geometry then its running properly. But in case of extrude geometry its not working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: Created a 3d cube using extrude geometry with hole using parallax3d library. Now I want to add a texture. I have already tried too many times but its not working . If I add texture then object color is changed to white.